# How run a progress bar to indicate the other process is busy in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I am working on a project and I need to show the User a 'busy progress bar' or a 'GUI element' until another process is completed. Is there any way I can do it without using threads. The snippet as shown:

```
     QProcess compile;
     QProgressDialog *dialog = new QProgressDialog();
     dialog->setMinimum(0);
     dialog->setMaximum(0);

     compile.start("make", QStringList()<< send.at(2) << "-j6" << "IN=" + QFileInfo(send.at(0)).absolutePath() + "/" +QFileInfo(send.at(0)).baseName() << "OUT=/home/venkatesh/MooNMD_Working/ParMooN_Out/cd2d/" + send.at(1) + ".exe" << "&");
     while(compile.waitForFinished(-1))
     {
          dialog->exec();
     }
     dialog->close();
```

But the busy progress bar does not close on it's own at the end of make command. What are my options?

Comment: Why are you calling `compile.start(` ... `<< "&");`

Isn't this the same as calling `QProcess::startDetatched()`? You lose access to the process and all communication with it.

Answer (score 4):

You should do something like this:

```
QProcess compile;
QProgressDialog *dialog = new QProgressDialog;
dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
dialog->setRange(0,0);
connect(&compile, SIGNAL(finished(int)), dialog, SLOT(close()));

compiler.start("myprog.exe");
dialog->exec();
```

Having `dialog->exec();` in a loop makes no sense. It will also block when you call `dialog->exec();` meaning your loop won't finish.

Comment: Thank you thuga for a beautiful code.But then,I get following errors:                                                                 1.'d' was not declared in this scope.                                                                       2.'connect' was not declared in this scope. Please help me understand the code. I am new to Qt. And I think there is a slight correction:I think it has to be QProgressDialog.

Comment: @Denzil Sorry about that. It was supposed to be dialog, not d. I've changed it now. If it keeps saying `connect was not declared in this scope`, try `QObject::connect(&compile, SIGNAL(finished(int)), dialog, SLOT(close()))`

Comment: :I tried your code again. But, this time the dialog is not displayed at all.

Comment: @Denzil Did you show your dialog anywhere? You still need to have `dialog->exec()` or `dialog->show()` where you want to show your dialog.

Comment: Basically, I need to have something running in the screen when another process is running(make command is been executed.) I haven't done `dialog -> show` anywhere else. If you can suggest something that keeps the user informed about the process being running and gets terminated when the process is terminated, it would of great help

Comment: @Denzil What i have in the answer should do exactly that. I modified it a bit so it would be clear for you when to call dialog->exec().

Answer (score 0):

The `QProgressDialog` will only close when the value passed to `setValue` reaches the value set by `setMaximum`.

You have set both the minimum and maximum to be `0` so obviously the dialog will not function properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robbie. But since my intention is to make a busy progress bar until I reach, I need to set the values to 0